# Как скачать файл из инфоблока Битрикс24 в 1С?

Tags: 1с, битрикс24

Как скачать файл из инфоблока Битрикс24 в 1С?
Есть такого вида ссылка https://Домен/bizproc/processes/147/file/0/67609/P...
Есть такой код на 1С.

```
 Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("Домен",,"Логин","Пароль",,5,Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL());
    Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос("sofi-soft.bitrix24.ru/bizproc/processes/147/file/0/"+Строка(СтрТаб.DOCUMENT_ID)+"/PROPERTY_727/"+Строка(СтрТаб.ФайлВыгрузки)+"/?ncc=n&download=n"); Ответ = Соединение.Получить(Запрос);
Если Ответ.КодСостояния = 302 Тогда
АдресРесурса = Ответ.Заголовки.Получить("Location");

    Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос(АдресРесурса);
    Ответ = Соединение.Получить(Запрос);
    ДвоичныеДанныеКартинки = Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакДвоичныеДанные();
    Иначе
    ДвоичныеДанныеКартинки = Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакДвоичныеДанные();
    КонецЕсли; ДвоичныеДанныеКартинки.Записать("\\storage\Share\ДОКУМЕНТЫ_ТОВАРОСОПРОВОДИТЕЛЬНЫЕ\"+Строка(СтрТаб.DOCUMEN T_ID)+".jpg");
```

Изначальный ответ Код состояния 302. При 302 отправляю на скачку адрес из Заголовка. Локация . Все равно идет 302 код. И так по кругу. На выходе получаем пустой файл.

Comment: А что приходит в локации? Напишите ссылку.

Comment: https://auth2.bitrix24.net/oauth/authorize/?user_lang=ru&client_id=b24.58eb9a2f513488.09457247&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsofi-soft.bitrix24.ru%2Fbizproc%2Fprocesses%2F147%2Ffile%2F0%2F67531%2FPROPERTY_727%2F1306573%2F%3Fauth_service_id%3DBitrix24Net%26ncc%3Dy%26download%3Dn%26any%3D147%252Ffile%252F0%252F67531%252FPROPER

Comment: TY_727%252F1306573%252F&scope=auth,profile&response_type=code&mode=page&state=site_id%3Ds1%26backurl%3D%252Fbizproc%252Fprocesses%252F147%252Ffile%252F0%252F67531%252FPROPERTY_727%252F1306573%252F%253Fcheck_key%253D78eee8097f5c16dc3580977f4945b011%2526ncc%253Dy%2526download%253Dn%2526any%253D147%25252Ffile%25252F0%25252F67531%25252FPROPERTY_727%25252F1306573%25252F%26mode%3Dpage

Comment: Вот такая ссылка. Из двух кусков (один не влез в комментарий)

Comment: Если задаю эту ссылку через "Соединение запрос" То выдает 200 код но файл пустой.

Comment: Блин, так тяжело вникнуть. Самому бы пощупать... Тестового стенда нету?

Comment: По большому счету Вот Ссылка на файл которую дает битрикс (Там сейчас картинка) https://sofi-soft.bitrix24.ru/bizproc/processes/147/file/0/67609/PROPERTY_727/1306671/?ncc=y&download=y Вопрос как ее сохранить на диск через 1С.

Comment: При переходе по ссылке просит авторизацию, поэтому не могу попробовать скачать. Еще сейчас заметил, что у Вас в HTTP запросе в начале указан домен, хотя он там не нужен.